# Sort PHPActiveRecord array of objects alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, phpactiverecord

How can I sort a [`PHPActiveRecord`](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) array alphabetically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i ended up getting the array already ordered with phpactiverecord and order_by:

```
$books = Book::find('all', array('order' => 'title_en asc'));
```

and it sort of works...

Comment: It's either this (retrieve them sorted) or sort them afterwards in php with one of the default sorting functions.

Comment: You can accept your own answer if this is what you used in the end :)